# make-series in Kusto for missing Timestamp

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

In Azure data explorer we have multi options of the timespan to use, which they are "day, minute, second ... etc).
I added timestep like:
[image]
The raw data I have has interval of 10s. However data do not always come every 10sec.
Due to this reason when I plot chart for some time bwtween value is plotted as zero.
How can I replace value of zero with value just available before [image: Chart]

Logic
[[image: Logic]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9QzV.png

Result:[image: Result]
I tried different series function and mv-expand. I would like to know how can I replace zero values.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I do it:

```
let T = datatable
(
myid:int, 
mydate:datetime,
myval:int
)
[
1,datetime("2021-08-20 08:00"),1,
2,datetime("2021-08-20 08:01"),1,
3,datetime("2021-08-20 08:02"),2,
4,datetime("2021-08-20 08:03"),3,
5,datetime("2021-08-20 08:04"),1,
6,datetime("2021-08-20 08:06"),1,
7,datetime("2021-08-20 08:06"),2,
8,datetime("2021-08-20 08:09"),3,
9,datetime("2021-08-20 08:09"),4,
10,datetime("2021-08-20 08:09"),4
];
T
| make-series myval = max(myval) default=long(null) on mydate from datetime("2021-08-20 08:00") to datetime("2021-08-20 08:11")   step 1m //basis für forecast
| project mydate, myval, fillforward= series_fill_forward(myval) //fehlende Werte ersetzen
| mv-expand mydate,   myval, fillforward
```

If there is no value, it will take the last existing value. Hope this helps !

[image]