# Using KQL, how to retrieve a boundary value at the start of a range you want to interpolate on?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have a table that holds realtime values, but with large gaps. I want to retrieve interpolated values for a time range. If I do a simple `| where Date >= start` then, I will have a large empty gap at the start.
Instead, I would like to get a value at the for that boundary point that is the interpolation of the first value before and after the start time.

I came up with the method below, but I am hoping there is something simpler that is available.

```
let F = (T:(Date:datetime, Value:real), start:datetime ) 
{
    let prev = T | where isnotnull(Weight) | where Date > start | sort by Date desc | take 1;
    let next = T | where isnotnull(Weight) | where Date <= start| sort by Date desc | take 1;
    let x = toscalar(prev | summarize by Weight);
    let y = toscalar(next | summarize by Weight);
    let a = toscalar(prev | summarize by Date);
    let b = toscalar(next | summarize by Date);   
    let run = y-x;
    let rise = toint(b-a);
    let intercept = (run/rise)*toint(start - a) + x;
    print start, intercept | project Date=print_0, Value=print_1;
};
F((LongTermWeight | project Date, Value), datetime("2023-09-14"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a look at the make-series command. This is a nice way to interpolate values. One example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433237/make-series-in-kusto-for-missing-timestamp/77125659#77125659). In this example, the last available value is used for interpolation ([**series_fill_forward**](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-forwardfunction)). Another popular option is using [**series_fill_linear**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-linearfunction). This will return a linear interpolation for missing values.